# How do I fix the NotImplementedError in Python?

Tags: python, python-turtle, skulpt

I am a beginner coding so I don't know a lot about python, but if you answered this it would be much appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
import turtle
def clear1():
  import os
  os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else "printf '\033c'")
```

then a bunch of turtle code. Then after the turtle code:

```
choice = input("Want to get started? ")
while choice == "yes" or choice == "Yes":
  clear1()
```

Output:

```
NotImplementedError: os is not yet implemented in Skulpt on line 1
```

And I am very confused because I use the exact same algorithm in a different project and it works

Link to current project: https://repl.it/@WeirdDragon/RPS#main.py

Link to project it worked on: https://repl.it/@WeirdDragon/Fortune-teller#main.py

Comment: So does that mean os cannot be used?

Comment: Runs fine when I copy the file and run it locally in idle.  Also, I would add that it is good practice to put all import statements at the top of the file, instead of immediately before use.   This prevents unnecessary repeated imports and also cases where you reorder bits of code and end up without imports that you need in the right places

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, Skulpt uses old and unsupported Python 2.7 for "Python (with turtle)" projects but modern Python 3.8 for non-turtle projects. Apparently, Skulpt's 2.7 does not support the module `os`. So, you can use either `turtle` or `os` but not both.

Comment: It's just the `os` module that's missing from skulpt and it supports both 3.7ish and 2.7ish. The os module doesn't make much sense in a browser.

Comment: @albertjan Wrong. Skulpt supports `os` for non-turtle projects, as is obvious from the question (and you can try it yourself).

Comment: https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/blob/master/src/lib/os.py ‍♂️

Comment: Only one of the two projects in the question actually runs on skulpt.